# .class file too large

Tags: android, kotlin, runtimeexception, .class-file

I have a kotlin file with a function that returns a list of strings with 10,000 elements, but when compiling it generates an error, saying that the .class file is too large.  What I can do?

```
 return listOf( "string 1", "string 2", ... "string 10,000" )
```

each string is between 5 and 20 characters or so. The file has nothing but the function

error

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Error generating class file path/../LiveLiterals$FileName.cass (compile from [path..]) class to large
```

Comment: Source code really isn't the best place to put a list of 10K items.  That should probably be a file or a database.

Comment: A simple text list should be saved as asset into your app. You can then load and return it if needed.